# Copy rows in Excel and increment a column

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create an Excel macro that will take a spreadsheet that has `n` number of rows in it and copy each row as many times as a number located within one of the cells.

Also it would increment one of the numbers within a cell. For example, I have a layout like the following:

```
Column1    Column2    Column3     Column4, etc..  
Data-a     Data-a     1000        5  
Data-b     Data-b     4600        10
```

The result would be:

```
Column1    Column2    Column3     Column4  
Data-a     Data-a     1000        5  
Data-a     Data-a     1001        5  
Data-a     Data-a     1002        5  
Data-a     Data-a     1003        5  
Data-a     Data-a     1004        5  
Data-b     Data-b     4600        10  
Data-b     Data-b     4601        10  
Data-b     Data-b     4602        10  
Data-b     Data-b     4603        10  
Data-b     Data-b     4604        10  
Data-b     Data-b     4605        10  
Data-b     Data-b     4606        10  
Data-b     Data-b     4607        10  
Data-b     Data-b     4608        10   
Data-b     Data-b     4609        10
```

Hopefully this makes sense. I'm looking for someone who may be a little more versed with this type of macro to shed some light or point me in the right direction.

Comment: Do you want to copy to a new worksheet or insert the new rows into the existing worksheet?

Answer (score 1):

I tested this code and it seemed to work ok. To make this work you need to select 'Data-a' in your inital list of data i.e. top-left hand cell.

There are three procedures:

1. InsertNewRows: This simply inserts the required number of blank new rows
2. ReplicateData: This populates the blank rows with the correct data
3. TransformData: This is the main procedure that loops through each line that needs replicating

---

```
Sub InsertNewRows(TargetRow As Integer, TargetCol As Integer, Reps As Integer)
    Dim iRep As Integer
    For iRep = 1 To Reps - 1
        Cells(TargetRow + iRep, TargetCol).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Next iRep
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub ReplicateData(TargetRow As Integer, TargetCol As Integer, Reps As Integer)
Dim iRep As Integer
    For iRep = 1 To Reps - 1
        With Cells(TargetRow, TargetCol)
            .Offset(iRep, 0).Value = .Value
            .Offset(iRep, 1).Value = .Offset(0, 1).Value
            .Offset(iRep, 2).Value = .Offset(0, 2).Value + iRep
            .Offset(iRep, 3).Value = .Offset(0, 3).Value
        End With
    Next iRep
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub TransformData()
Dim nRows As Long

nRows = ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

Dim StartingRow As Integer
Dim StartingColumn As Integer
Dim NumberOfReplications As Integer
Dim RowOffset

StartingRow = ActiveCell.Row
StartingColumn = ActiveCell.Column
NumberOfReplications = 0
RowOffset = 0

Dim iIterations As Integer

For iIterations = 1 To nRows

If Not VBA.IsEmpty(Cells(StartingRow + RowOffset, StartingColumn)) Then
   NumberOfReplications = Cells(StartingRow + RowOffset, StartingColumn).Offset(0, 3)
   InsertNewRows StartingRow + RowOffset, StartingColumn, NumberOfReplications
   ReplicateData StartingRow + RowOffset, StartingColumn, NumberOfReplications
   RowOffset = RowOffset + NumberOfReplications
End If

Next iIterations

End Sub
```